# It doesn't execute my update query

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3, procedures

I have this procedure called updates:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `updates`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updates` (IN `ids` INT(11), IN `name` VARCHAR(20), IN `ape` VARCHAR(20), IN `pass` VARCHAR(20), IN `dpto` VARCHAR(20), IN `rols` VARCHAR(20))  BEGIN
UPDATE usuario SET name_user=name, apellidos=ape, pw_user = pass, depto=dpto, rol_user=rols WHERE id_user=ids;
END$$
```

And this is my php code:

```
$query= "CALL updates('".$_POST['id_user']."','".$_POST["usern"]."' ,'".$_POST["apell"]."' ,  '".$_POST["passwd"]."' , '".$_POST["depto"]."' , '".$_POST["rolu"]."')";
```

But it doesn't execute, please help :(

Comment: use single quotes around names in post array

Comment: What is result of store procedure call? Is there any error?

Comment: Use error reporting ([`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php), [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), [`PDO::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php), depending on what you use).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
$query = "{CALL dbo.updates
('".$_POST['id_user']."','".$_POST["usern"]."' ,'".$_POST["apell"]."'
,  '".$_POST["passwd"]."' , '".$_POST["depto"]."' ,
'".$_POST["rolu"]."') }";
```